# List index out of range using Pandas. How can I get it to access just one index in my list instead of multiple?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, parsing, indexing

I’m having trouble with my code. I’m making a macro that will parse data from an [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) sheet. Ideally, I’d like it to get the row number from the sheet and use that row number to grab the cell value on its same row in another column. This is the code I have so far:

```
    ## OPENING FILES ##
    # Opens the path to the prints
    entries = Path(r'C:\Users\jmcintosh\LIDT Project (copy)\LIDT Project\Solidworks Test (DEV)')
    # Opens Excel sheet for reading
    xlEntries = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\jmcintosh\LIDT Project (copy)\LIDT Project\LIDT New Webspec         Titles 2.0.xlsx')


## Variable Definitions ## (Stick to CamelCase "firstLast")
partNumbers = [] # Make partNumbers the array for partnumbers, gathers the names as well as the partnumbers
specName = []    # Create an array to hold the specification names--this becomes the value of the cells
rowNumber = []   # Array for desired row numbers
specValue = []   # Array for desired specifications

# A 'for' loop that allows iteration through the directory of names.
for entry in entries.iterdir():
        partNumbertemp = re.findall('[0-9]+', entry.name)
        partNumbers.append(int(partNumbertemp[0]))    # Appends the array with the regex function to parse only the integers of the file name to be used later.

# A 'while' loop to remove blank file names from directory issues
while ([] in partNumbers):
        partNumbers.remove([])

fileCount = (len(partNumbers))  # Number of files being edited
rowCount = len(xlEntries['StockNumber']) # Number of rows in the Excel document
stockNumber = xlEntries['StockNumber']  # Column of stock numbers
print(partNumbers[0])

# A 'while' loop to find the row numbers and the the specification name and value of each of the desired row numbers
# Reset count for 'while' loop

k = 0
while (k<fileCount):
        rowNumbertemp = xlEntries.loc[xlEntries['StockNumber'] == partNumbers[k]].index.to_numpy()

        for row in rowNumbertemp:
            rowNumber.append(int(rowNumbertemp))
        specNametemp = xlEntries.loc[rowNumber[k],"Pat's Proposed Change"]

        for spec in specNametemp:
            specName.append(specNametemp)
        specValuetemp = xlEntries.loc[rowNumber[k],"StringValue"]

        for value in specValuetemp:
            specValue.append(specValuetemp)
        k = k + 1

        #print(len(rowNumber))
        #print(k)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jmcintosh\LIDT PRoject (copy)\LIDT Project\NEW EDMUND OPTICS LIDT\LIDT_MULTIPLE_FILE_TEST.py", line 64, in <module>
    specNametemp = xlEntries.loc[rowNumber[k],"Pat's Proposed Change"]
                                 ~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This the full traceback error.

This is what it prints from rowNumber:

```
[2382]
[2382, 2590]
[2382, 2590, 2065]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587, 2588]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587, 2588, 2589]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2062]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2062, 2063]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2062, 2063, 2064]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2384]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2384, 2385]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2384, 2385, 2592]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2384, 2385, 2592, 2593]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2384, 2385, 2592, 2593, 2067]
[2382, 2590, 2065, 2383, 2591, 2066, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2587, 2588, 2589, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2384, 2385, 2592, 2593, 2067, 163]
```

Why is it not accessing a single index of my array? Why are there multiple entries per index?

I feel as though that is making it an error, but I don’t have any clue about how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the issue is with the rowNumber array. In the while loop, you are appending multiple row numbers to the rowNumber array for each iteration of the loop. Then, in the subsequent for loop, you are trying to access the value at the index of rowNumber[k], which is actually a list of row numbers. This is causing the IndexError you are seeing. To fix this, you should only append a single row number to the rowNumber array for each iteration of the while loop. Here's an updated version of the while loop:

```
while (k<fileCount):
rowNumbertemp = xlEntries.loc[xlEntries['StockNumber'] == partNumbers[k]].index.to_numpy()
rowNumber.append(int(rowNumbertemp[0]))  # Append only the first row number found
specNametemp = xlEntries.loc[rowNumber[k],"Pat's Proposed Change"]
specName.append(specNametemp)
specValuetemp = xlEntries.loc[rowNumber[k],"StringValue"]
specValue.append(specValuetemp)
k = k + 1
```

Update:

```
k = 0
while (k<fileCount):
        rowNumbertemp = xlEntries.loc[xlEntries['StockNumber'] == partNumbers[k]].index.to_numpy()
                
        rowNumber.append(rowNumbertemp[0])
        specNametemp = xlEntries.loc[rowNumber[k],"Pat's Proposed Change"]
        for spec in specNametemp:
            specName.append(specNametemp)
        specValuetemp = xlEntries.loc[rowNumber[k],"StringValue"]
        for value in specValuetemp:
            specValue.append(specValuetemp)
        k = k + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback !I just tried it and i get a traceback saying "index  is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"

Comment: Try the code above under update. Looking at things in another way.

Comment: Sorry same traceback error

Comment: I think its saying that the array is empty when we first access it

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT